# Could the estimated stellar mass for the Milky Way galaxy include brown dwarfs?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, dark-matter, galaxies, brown-dwarfs

Trying to find an estimate for the stellar mass of the MW galaxy, I found [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4340) and the estimated stellar mass is $~6.5 \times 10^{10} M_{\odot}$.
I was also trying to understand the methods used to determine this number, one of them used the measured luminosity of the MW and then multiplying it by the mass-to-luminosity ratio.

Anyways, I am actually not interested in the methods now, but there is still one question that confuses me. Could this estimated stellar mass by some sort of error have a **significant** part of it in non-luminous matter like brown dwarfs ? Like if there exists hundreds of billions of brown dwarfs, then are their masses considered dark matter or they are included in the stellar mass ? In other words, are the methods used reliable enough to be able to count only the luminous part of the mass ?

I ask this because I know there is still missing baryonic matter, so how can we be sure that what we are calculating is actually the stars and not other dim objects ?

Comment: Closely related question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149560/according-to-the-initial-mass-function-should-there-be-more-brown-dwarfs-than-r?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another closely related question ([According to the initial mass function, should there be more brown dwarfs than red dwarfs?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149560/according-to-the-initial-mass-function-should-there-be-more-brown-dwarfs-than-r?lq=1) ), I showed that the number of
brown dwarfs (with $M<0.075M_{\odot}$) is a factor of five smaller than the number of red dwarf stars
(stars with $0.075<M/M_{odot}<0.5$),
using the widely adopted [Chabrier (2005)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005ASSL..327...41C) lognormal initial mass function (IMF). The approximate
correctness of this analytic IMF has been demonstrated using
censuses of stars and brown dwarfs in young open clusters
(e.g. [Andersen et al. 2008](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008ApJ...683L.183A) ).

Given that the average red dwarf in this calculation has a mass of
about $0.2 M_{\odot}$ and the average brown dwarf a mass of about
$0.06M_{\odot}$, you can easily see that **the total mass in brown
dwarfs is only about 6 percent of that in red dwarfs and a very small
component of the baryonic mass of the Galaxy**. Therefore brown dwarfs are not
responsible for baryonic dark matter. As the luminosities of these
low-mass objects scales roughly as $M^3$, you can also see that brown
dwarfs contribute almost nothing to the luminosity of a Galaxy.

Turning directly to your question - how does the presence of brown
dwarfs affect the mass-to-luminosity ratio? Well, they contribute a few
percent to the numerator and almost nothing to the
denominator.

**Therefore, at most, brown dwarfs may *add* a few percent
to the stellar mass determined from a Galaxy's luminosity.**