# What is the luminosity of the Milky Way?

Tags: astronomy, galaxies, luminosity, milky-way

This question may appear to be the same as [What is the luminosity of the Milky Way galaxy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148964/2451), but that question references a value of $5\times 10^{36}\space W$, which comes from a Wiki page which references an article from 1999.  While Rob Jeffries provides some excellent insight into the physics behind the value, it doesn't provide an objective answer to the original question.  Does anyone have a more recent value for the absolute luminosity of the Milky Way that can be referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the [best current estimate](https://doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/809/1/96) is that the Milky Way galaxy has an absolute magnitude of

$$^0M_r - 5 \log h = -21.00^{+0.38}_{-0.37}$$

which is equivalent to a luminosity of $5.4 \times 10^{36}$ to $1.1 \times 10^{37}$ W.  This makes the Milky Way one of the brightest known spiral galaxies.